# Issue with width/style of PopupWindow

Tags: android, popupwindow

I'm using a PopupWindow to show some subcategories when clicking on a ListView item.
I'm using the same layout for the `ListView` rows (categories) and for the PopupWindow (categories).

My problem is that I set the width of my `PopupWindow` to that of my row item view, but when it is displayed, it's a bit narrower, with some kind of border.

On the screenshot below I put the PopupWindow on top of the ListView to se the difference

Why is it smaller? How can I remove this border?

[image]

**listView.setOnItemClickListener(...)**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {        

            showPopup(HomeActivity.this, layout_base, v, position);
        }
    }
});
```

**showPopup(...)**

```
public void showPopup(Context context, View parent, View view, int position){

    /*
     * Compute popup position and size
     */

    int[] itemPosition = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(itemPosition);

    int item_width = view.getWidth();
    int item_height = view.getHeight();

    int nChildren = GlobalVars.menuItemArray[position].children.size();

    int popup_height = item_height * nChildren; 

    /*
     * Build the view
     */

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    LinearLayout popupContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
    popupContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    popupContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LayoutParams params;

    params = new LayoutParams(item_width, item_height);
    popupContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

    for(int i=0; i<nChildren; i++){

        RelativeLayout menu_row = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_row, null);        

        popupContainer.addView(menu_row, params);
    }

    mPopup.setContentView(popupContainer);
    mPopup.setHeight(popup_height);
    mPopup.setWidth(item_width);

    mPopup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);         

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to remove the background of the PopupWindow using:

```
mPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

Comment: you can just use "null" as parameter, saves you some memory.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. Android is full of quirks and bugs I spent more time fighting the API than doing actual coding.

Comment: @manmal When I set it to null, my PopupWindow becomes unable to dismiss when I click outside of it. No idea why. (In case anyone run into this problem)